# Is DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcasted for every retry of failed download?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-download-manager

`DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` is the broadcast intent sent by download manager when download completes with different statuses(success, failed).
It will retry max 5 times. is this event broadcasted for every retry or one time finally after 5 retires?